# VHDL synthesis doubt

Tags: fpga, vhdl, spartan-6

1. Does the synthesis tool consider an initial value of a signal given before begin of the architecture. What happens when this value is not a constant but another signal.
2. is it better to provide initial values to signals or use reset?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on who else drives the signal, an initialization value could be treated arbitrarily by the tool (hopefully just ignored if it doesn't make sense).
Besides, the concept of initialization makes in general no sense for a signal. A signal is a wire and a wire is *driven* (e.g. by logic or a flip flop), not initialized. Therefore it is usually more consistent to keep signal declaration and assignments (i.e. driving by something) separate as they are logically distinct concepts.

Comment: thanks. so we can leave all signals uninitialized in the declaration section?

Comment: Yes. As I said, initialization is a software concept and can lead to confusion when designing hardware.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use reset. When simulating, everything is initialised to 'X'; when synthesised, it will randomly be 1 or 0. Initial values don't work in synthesis, so you need a reset.

Comment: if a sub-module requires reset but the top module has no reset port then what to do?

Comment: Then you have to add one if you want it to work in synthesis.

Comment: That's not true. Simulation initializes signals, if not defined otherwise, with 'U' (uninitialized). 'X' means error. Most synthesis tools regard initialization values. It's possible to set different values for initialization and reset. Xilinx tools assume undefined init values to be '0'.

Comment: @Paebbels that is usually true, except when it isn't. My experience with Xilinx tools is that this kind of choices can lead to very subtle errors or mismatches with simulation..

Comment: @Paebbels other tools are typically more robust (e.g. Synopsys DC) but the fundamental point remains: initializing a signal makes sense only when it is a constant. Otherwise it's conceptually confusing and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targetting an FPGA then signal initialisation *can* make sense and the tools do (in my experience) support it - and have for a number of years now.

You usually want to use a reset clause though for most things as debugging can get very tedious if you have to reconfigure every time to stimulate a problem, rather than just wiggle the reset pin to get all your logic back to a known state.

I usually only use initialisation for the logic related to the reset synchronisation signals to ensure that the simulation and synthesis match and hold the reset actively low (rather than a temporary 'U' in simulation) until the external reset signal has gone inactive.